# Приложение падает при включении из служб (путь к файлу)

Tags: c++

Понял, что все дело в пути к файлу конфигурации. Ну и с путям в общем.

Пусть сам exe лежит в папке C:\a\b\c\d и в ней же лежит файл конфигурации. Судя по тому, что он не находится, то "родная" папка при таком запуске меняется. Как сделать так, чтобы и при таком запуске прописывалась "родительской" папка экзешника?
Или как-то находился в системе нужный файл.

PS запуск в службе происходит через ShellExecute.

Comment: А как вы определяете текущий каталог, из которого берете конфигурацию? У вас там используются относительные пути, небось?

Comment: И, кстати, что вы указываете в параметре lpDirectory при вызове ShellExecute?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов указываю nil (да, запуск из служб на delphi, от другого разработчика) 
Да, относительные. Никак не определяю. Как его определить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запуск приложения через `ShellExecute` с параметром `lpDirectory`, равным `NULL` приводит к следующему эффекту. Текущий каталог процесса-потомка будет тем же, что и у родителя и если потомок не лежит в том же каталоге, ваш файл с конфигурацией не будет найден.

Есть два варианта: явно указывать нужный каталог через `lpDirectory` или получать каталог, где находится EXE в нем самом через `GetModuleFileName(NULL, ...)`. Второй вариант, IMHO, более универсальный и не требует переписывания сервиса.

Comment: Да, я смотрел в эту сторону же. Но `GetModuleFileName` выдает путь с *.exe. Как мне получить уже без имени файла? Вот так я получаю путь:

    `char szPath[MAX_PATH];`
    `GetModuleFileName(0, (LPWSTR)szPath, MAX_PATH);`

Comment: Это уже элементарное использование строковых функций типа strrchr('\\');

Comment: Точно, забыл о ней. Спасибо!